# How to call Database.DuplicateError inside Database.SaveResult for loop?

Tags: apex, dml

I'm using this code to get the error ids

```
List<Database.SaveResult> updateResults;
    updateResults = Database.upsert(arudate, false);
  for(Integer i=0;i<updateResults.size();i++){

        if (updateResults.get(i).isSuccess()){
            updateResults.get(i).getId();
        }
        else if (!updateResults.get(i).isSuccess()){
            // DML operation failed
            Database.Error error = updateResults.get(i).getErrors().get(0);
            String failedDML = error.getMessage();
            arudate.get(i);//failed record from the list
                                system.debug('Failed ID'+arudate.get(i).Id);

        }

    }
```

But, i would like to get the specific duplicate error message and duplicate rule using this code

```
// Insertion failed due to duplicate detected
for(Database.Error duplicateError : sr.getErrors()){
    Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = 
              ((Database.DuplicateError)duplicateError).getDuplicateResult();
    System.debug('Duplicate records have been detected by ' + 
              duplicateResult.getDuplicateRule());
    System.debug(duplicateResult.getErrorMessage());
}
```

My concerns is, how to use the duplicate `getDuplicateResult()` inside the for loop of Database.Result. I'm receiving an error because updateResults.get(i).getErrors().get(0) is an individual record while `sr.getErrors()` returns lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
List<Database.SaveResult> updateResults;
    updateResults = Database.upsert(arudate, false);
  for(Integer i=0;i<updateResults.size();i++){

        if (!updateResults[i].isSuccess()){
            // DML operation failed
            for (Database.Error error : saveResult.getErrors()) {

                String failedDML = error.getMessage();

                if (error instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {

                    Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = 
                      ((Database.DuplicateError)error).getDuplicateResult();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

From the docs, check if the error is an instance of a duplicate result. You will still have to iterate over the save results and then iterate over the errors for each save result. So it is a combination of both your code examples

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm#apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult

Comment: there is no value after the if condition 
if (error instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {

Here is the log inside getErrors() loop
Database.Error[getFields=();getMessage=There is an existing record with the same email or mobile.;getStatusCode=UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION;]

Comment: @Von - There does not need to be. It evaluates to true or false

Comment: is there a way to get duplicate error / duplicate rule?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm#apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult AND https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DuplicateError.htm- There is a method for that. Are we on to new questions now? If so and this answered your original question please mark answer appropriately and start a separate question.

Comment: Yes. I try to debug inside the loop

for (error instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {}

But it does not return a value

Comment: Then debug `error instanceof Database.DuplicateError` if it is false then the error was not due to a duplicate rule or you API version is not set to at least v33. Other than that, The answer illustrates how you use it inside a loop. You can try removing the if statement and see if it gives you the results you expect